# Vuetify v-data-table row click event with modifiers

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want two separate click events on my vuetify datatable.
One with a normal left click and one with an additional modifier (SHIFT / CTRL and left click).
Is that even possible?

Here is a codepen with a not working example:
https://codepen.io/borsTiHD/pen/YzpVrNJ

`@click="clickEvent"` and `@click:row.ctrl="rowCtrlClicked"` is not working.

Comment: UPD: `@click.native.ctrl` works, but it works on all datatable

Comment: Thanks, thats working. I just don't have the typical vuetify arguments passed in my method. Is there a way to combine this? I would prefere not to set a global variable in my component.

Comment: You can populate the `items` slot - thus you can do `<template v-slot:items="{item}"><tr @click.native.ctrl="myHandler(item)">`

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I will try that out. It is a little more complicated than I thought. I need to rebuild my hole table this way. I have many "custom" column templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with a global key eventlistener in my component. I found an example here:
https://codepen.io/ryancwynar/pen/jOWoXZw

My code:
I set `this.registerKeyHandler(true/false)` in `created()` and `beforeDestroy()`

```
registerKeyHandler(register) {
    if (register) {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyHandler)
        window.addEventListener('keyup', this.keyHandler)
    } else {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyHandler)
        window.removeEventListener('keyup', this.keyHandler)
    }
},
keyHandler(event) {
    if (!event.key === 'Control' && !event.key === 'Shift') return false
    if (event.key === 'Control' && event.type === 'keydown') {
        this.ctrlKeyOn = true
    } else if (event.key === 'Control' && event.type === 'keyup') {
        this.ctrlKeyOn = false
    } else if (event.key === 'Shift' && event.type === 'keydown') {
        this.shiftKeyOn = true
    } else if (event.key === 'Shift' && event.type === 'keyup') {
        this.shiftKeyOn = false
    }
},
```